# Agg counts on nested objects in elasitcsearch query count only once

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

we have a mapping with nested objects.
We use it for storing variants in an ecommerce environment.

To build filters in ecommerce we check agg bucket counts.
What happens now is that we get agg counts for every variant that this matching.
But i would like to count only once per parent (even if more than one children match).

here is our mapping:

```
{
"products": {
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
            "product_id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "variants": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "brand": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "color": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example of documents:

```
 {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "5e42f759de235d5b42e6e35524141bd2cfcbc5d0",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "product_id": "5e42f759de235d5b42e6e35524141bd2cfcbc5d0",
                "variants": [
                    {

                        "color": [
                            "Black"
                        ]
                        "brand": "Fackelmann"
                    },
                    {
                        "color": [],
                        "brand": "Fackelmann"
                    },
                    {
                        "color": [],
                        "brand": "Fackelmann",
                    },
                    {
                        "color": [],
                        "brand": "Fackelmann"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "products",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "768af68018654b04f20d32003348ee9bd81d9f65",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "product_id": "768af68018654b04f20d32003348ee9bd81d9f65",
                "variants": [
                    {

                        "color": [
                            "Grey"
                        ]
                        "brand": "Fackelmann"
                    },
                    {
                        "color": [],
                        "brand": "Fackelmann"
                    },
                    {
                        "color": [],
                        "brand": "Fackelmann",
                    },
                    {
                        "color": [],
                        "brand": "IKEA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

in this example we get those counts for aggs:

```
brand:Fackelmann[7]
brand:IKEA[1]
color:Grey[1]
color:Black[1]
```

What i expect to get is:

```
brand:Fackelmann[2]
brand:IKEA[1]
color:Grey[1]
color:Black[1]
```

Comment: why is Fackelmann[2] ? Could paste your query in the question?